# cannot get ui:image work

Tags: uibinder

I tried to use gwt's uiBinder to get an image, but it wont' work,

in the .xml file, i defined:

```
<ui:with field='res' type="com.my.services.email.client.Resources"/>
<ui:image field="testImage" resource="{res.calIcon}">
```

and i have a Resources.java file to define the image resource:

```
public interface Resources extends ClientBundle {
 Resources INSTANCE = GWT.create(Resources.class);

        @Source("img/cal.png")
 ImageResource calIcon();
}
```

and gwt complained:

```
[ERROR] No com.google.gwt.resources.client.ClientBundle$Source annotation and no resources found with default extensions
```

anyone knows what's wrong with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, and after several reading and trying, I found that there is no need to declare the image tag in order to access the image, once you declare `<ui:with field='res' type="com.my.services.email.client.Resources"/>` you can retrieve the image directly.

This is my code, I used two images for a Pushbutton

```
<ui:with field='res' type='com.ttt.client.resources.ImageResources'/>
  ...
      <g:PushButton ui:field='r0Button'>
          <g:upFace image='{res.icoStatusR0}'>R0</g:upFace>
          <g:downFace image='{res.icoStatusR0pushed}'>R0</g:downFace>
      </g:PushButton>
  ...
```

For the resource file, make sure that the path of the images is correct. I used the Wizard to generate mine, so I'am sure that the path is correct.